# How do I disassemble a slide whistle in order to clean it?

Tags: maintenance, instrument-cleaning

How do I disassemble it so that I can clean it?

[image]

<sub>(click to enlarge)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The base should just unscrew...

[image]

Comment: How do you loosen the screw on this? I can't get it off on mine.

Answer (score 1):

On the original *swanee whistle* or *lotus flute*, the end doesn't even unscrew. It just pulls off (carefully), but yours looks like a modern version, so will unscrew at the knurled end.

Comment: The Chinese version of the metal slide whistle that I have is held together by the indent in the body of the whistle and doesn't pull apart or unscrew ( I repaired one by drilling out the rivet dent and replacing it with a set screw.). I clean the other one I have by pouring hot water down the air channel.

Comment: @AlphonsoBalvenie - mine is a very heavy, possibly ebony model, metal lined, at least 70 yrs old. The endcap pushes on over thread at the end (not a threaded end, but sewing thread!).